# Adding "Monsters" to a TileMap - LIBGDX

Tags: java, libgdx

Thanks to alot of help from diff people willing to kindly share their help I have been able to read tilemaps and add my player start to the tilemap

```
for (int x = 0; x < layer3.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < layer3.getHeight(); y++) {
        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = layer3.getCell(x, y);
        if (cell == null)
            continue;
        if (cell.getTile() == null)
            continue;
        if (cell != null) {
            TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();
            if (tile != null) {
                if (layer3.getCell(x, y).getTile().getProperties()
                            .containsKey("Start"))
                            player.position.set(x, y);
```

However I would like to also place my monsters on the tilemap like the player, with the exception of i have multiple places on the tilemap to spawn monsters. The below code will only allow me to spawn one monster

```
for (int x = 0; x < layer2.getWidth(); x++) {
    for (int y = 0; y < layer2.getHeight(); y++) {
        TiledMapTileLayer.Cell cell = layer2.getCell(x, y);
        if (cell == null)
            continue;
        if (cell.getTile() == null)
            continue;
        if (cell != null) {
            TiledMapTile tile = cell.getTile();
            if (tile != null) {
                if (layer2.getCell(x, y).getTile().getProperties()
                        .containsKey("monster"))
                        monsters.position.set(x,y);
```

How could I spawn multiple monsters instead of one?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a list of Monsters

```
Array<Monster> monsters = new Array<Monster> //libgdx Array
```

And instead of this:

```
monsters.position.set(x,y); //wrong!
```

add a new monster:

```
monsters.add(new Monster(x, y)); //right!
```

Of course, use the parameters x and y in your monster contructor to set its position.